# Use Opportunity Standard Controller to populate Id on a lookup field on contact

Tags: visualforce, controller, standardcontroller

I have created a Visualforce page to create multiple contacts from an opportunity and I am trying to populate the opportunity id as a lookup field on the created contact. I am using the the getRecord() method however when I try to add the variable to set the field value the contact record is created and the field is blank.

```
public class addApprenticeDetails_CX {

public String fName { get;set; }
public String lName { get;set; }
public String email { get;set; }
public String accName { get;set; }
public Id AccId { get;set;}
public List<Account> accList { get;set;} 

public Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
public addApprenticeDetails_CX(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    this.opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    system.debug('Opportunity' + opp.id);
}

    public PageReference callLookup(){
        accList = [Select id,Name from Account];
        PageReference pr = new 
        PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetailsAccountLookup');
        pr.setRedirect(false);
        return pr;
    }

    public PageReference goBack(){
    accName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccName');
    AccId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('AccId');
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetails');
    pr.setRedirect(false);
    return pr;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        if(lName == null || lName == ''){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new 
        ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,
        'Last Name is Required!'));
        return null;
        }
        if(email == null || email == ''){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new 
        ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,
        'Email is Required!'));
        return null;    
        }
        else{
            Contact con = new Contact();

                    con.FirstName = fName;
                    con.LastName = lName;
                    con.Email = email;
                    con.AccountId = AccId;
                    con.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.
                    getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Corporate Contact')
                    .getRecordTypeId();
                    con.Third_Party_Opportunity__c = this.opp.id;
                insert con;


    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/addApprenticeDetails');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;

    }
    }
public list<Account> accs { get; set; }
public String searchString { get; set; }
public addApprenticeDetails_CX(){

}
public void search(){
    string searchQuery = 'select name, id from account where name like 
    \'%'+searchString+'%\'Limit 20';
    accs = Database.query(searchQuery);

}
public void remove(){
    accs.clear();
}
}
```

Comment: Is the page being used independently or embedded in an Opportunity page layout? Is the `id=` parameter present in the URL?

Comment: It is embedded in the opportunity page layout in a new section

Comment: I see some issues in your action methods (they're looking for parameters that won't be there), but I don't see the issue with your Opportunity id acquisition. Is that `debug` statement in your constructor showing a null value?

Comment: This controller is used for more than one VF page. The other one uses the search and remove method to search a list of accounts to select as the accountid for the newly created contact. I am not getting the debug statement at all.

Comment: I would suggest that you factor out "shared" methods into a service class and write one small controller for each Visualforce page. Debugging a shared controller gets really ugly really fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the standard controller and only used my custom controller. To get the opportunity Id in my lookup field I have used con.Third_Party_Opportunity__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); and this has solved my issue.